How to keep cmd window initiated by os.system open?
I am having problems with my python script. I am trying to automate a process using python on windows machine. I open an adb shell and run iperf using it. os.system initiates an cmd window and I can see the output. This code works as it should but there is a problem. Sometimes the windows closes arbitrarily. There is no specific time for it they run for a while and then they got close randomly (as it looks).
When I use the actual mobile iperf app for this task even there is problem with the network the app keep working thus I can run the iperf for days. However with the script, even though I use the same arguments the windows got close after sometime.
I tried adding && pause, >output.txt, && echo a at the end of the command however none of them worked. How can solve this problem? I want it to run until I close the windows manually just like it does on the mobile app.
directory = 'correct_directory'
buildCommand = 'adb'
if Protocol:  #TCP
    if link: #UL
        buildArgs = f'-s {serial_no} shell \"cd data/local/tmp && ./iperf2.1.4 -i2 -c{IP_address} -p{port} -t{str(time_)} \"'
        os.system('cd {} && start "" "{}" {}'.format(directory, buildCommand, buildArgs))
    else: #DL
        buildArgs = f'-s {serial_no} shell \"cd data/local/tmp && ./iperf2.1.4 -s -i2 -p{port} -P 1 \"'
        os.system('cd {} && start "" "{}" {}'.format(directory, buildCommand, buildArgs))


Try the command you use outside of Python, I assume it behaves the same. That would allow you to eliminate python from the calculation. Have you considered that the problem is on USB level? USB ports can get loose which makes the USB connection unstable. I would also open a second adb shell and leave it idle. If that shell closes, too the problem is adb (on PC and/or mobile side) or USB.

@Robert I tried the comment outside of Python. The problem was the -P 1 argument. When there is a network problem like delay the server shutdown itself after the timeout and the windows closses. I removed it and for the moment it looks like it is working fine. Thank you for the help.
